# Perl Regular Expressions sum numbers up

Tags: regex, perl, math

Im trying to find a way to add +100 to all those integers but I keep failing miserably.

I have these lines

```
  <devio1="875" devio2="7779" devio3="5635" devio4="154"/>
  <devio1="765" devio2="74779" devio3="31535" devio4="544"/>
  <devio1="4335" devio2="13" devio3="55635" devio4="1565"/>
```

I just cant get this to work in a good fasion. It never adds 100 to the integers, it only replaces them. What is the matter? Is this incorrect way of using regex and I have to use some other method?

```
 $d1 += 100;
 $d2 += 100;
 $d3 += 100;
 $d4 += 100;
 $d5 += 100;
 $d6 += 100;

s/<devio1="\d+" devio2="\d+" devio3="\d+" devio4="\d+" devio5="\d+"    devio6="\d+"\/>/<devio1="$d1" devio2="$d3" devio3="$d4" devio4="$d5" devio5="$d6" devio1="$d7"\/>/g;
```

Answer (score 4):

In a sane world, with `strict` turned on, this code generates a compile error.

If you leave that out, it merely does nothing, because the regex doesn't match the input you're showing.

If, somehow, it *were* to match, the values it would put into the output couldn't possibly have anything to do with the values in the input.

Perhaps you're looking for something like

```
s/(?<=")(\d+)(?=")/$1 + 100/eg;
```

which is a pretty sloppy way of parsing what looks like XML, but will do a good job of adding 100 to any sequence of digits between double quotes anyway.